# Functions for finding elements in a vector in R

Tags: r

I need to define a function that takes two arguments, a vector `V`, and a specific value `K` in the following form `count(V, K)` and return the number of occurrences of `K` in `V`.

```
vec <- c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5)  
count(vec, 2)  # Should return 3 - 2 occurs three times in vec  
count(vec, 4)  # Should return 4 
count(vec, 8)  # Should return 0 - 8 is not found in vec
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Note that most answers are only going to work for _integers_.  Doubles are more difficult because of floating-point precision.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so please tag it as such.

Comment: @SachaEpskamp -- Good point. I should have asked that myself.

Answer (score 2):

Any of these should work:

```
sum(vec==2)    # sum of logicals, TRUE==1
length(vec[vec==2])  #logical indexing
table(vec)["2"]   # alpha indexing of table object
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work for various types of `K`:

```
count <- function(V, K) {
    length(subset(V, V==K))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

works for `vec` lengths not exorbitantly long:
    rle(sort(vec))

And per Joshua's comment: depending on your data, you may need to use `floor` or similar functions to make sure "equal" elements of `vec` are viewed as identical.